# Call self.viewDidAppear when App comes to foreground

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I would like to have my app call viewDidAppear again when the user brings the app to  the foreground.

```
- (void)appReturnsActive{

    //THIS IS THE BIT THAT DOESNT WORK, BUT [self.viewDidLoad] DOES WORK
    [self.viewDidAppear];
}
```

I am creating appReturnsActive in my viewDidAppear method like this. It works well:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
selector:@selector(appReturnsActive) name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification 
object:nil];
```

I can do self.viewDidLoad, but I can't choose viewDidAppear. Does anyone know how I might get this to work?

Thank you!!

Comment: Please get a better grasp on the dot notation.  It is not correct for this case.  You use brackets **or** dot, not both for the same call.  By convention you never use dot notation for void functions either.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are simply calling it wrong. It should be

```
[self viewDidAppear:YES];
```

However, one should never call this or any of the viewDidLoad, viewWillAppear and so on. Put the code you want to run in `viewDidAppear:(BOOL)` in a separate method and call that method.

hope it helps!

Comment: So the smart way to do it would be to create a new method, and call that method from both viewDidAppear as well as the appReturnsActive? Is this just to prevent from clutter/keeping things more organized?

Comment: It is to prevent unwanted behavior by not manually calling a function that is normally called by the OS.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried `[self viewDidAppear:YES]` or `[self viewDidAppear:NO]` ?

Answer (score 1):

When using the containment API, use [`– beginAppearanceTransition:animated:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/beginAppearanceTransition:animated:) and `– endAppearanceTransition`:

> If you are implementing a custom container controller, use this method to tell the child that its views are about to appear or disappear. Do not invoke viewWillAppear:, viewWillDisappear:, viewDidAppear:, or viewDidDisappear: directly.

Calling addSubView will automatically trigger `viewWillAppear:` and `viewDidAppear:` if the view's viewController is a child view controller, therefore calling `viewWillAppear:` directly will trigger view will appearance method twice.  Using beginAppearanceTransition:animated:`and`– endAppearanceTransition` will suppress the automatic behaviour so you only get it called once.

Answer (score 0):

The method `viewDidAppear:` will be called automatically every time the view become visible, there is no need to call it by your self. If you have some code on this method that you need to run from other places I recommend you to add a new method containing those instructions. `viewDidAppear:` will also perform view related operations that can penalize the performance. All the ways, if you need to call it, you are missing the `BOOL` parameter, see the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewDidAppear%3a).